# Dependecy Injection causing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, dependency-injection, websocket

OK I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#section10) about Web Sockets, And I understand 99% of how the example code works. As for the 1%, it deals with the Dependency Injection. After researching DI, I understand that classes become dependent on a object from a class(ether itself or some other) in order to function. Here is how it is used.

```
package org.example.websocket;

...
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer {

    @Inject
    private DeviceSessionHandler sessionHandler;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
    }

    ...
}
```

I understand that the theory here is the class "DeviceWebSocketServer" is dependent on "DeviceSessionHandler" in order to function. However, when I run this code I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the logcat.

So I found out that the reason why is because sessionHandler is never initialized and is just hanging out being null and throwing Exceptions around like they are free. Isn't that purpose of the @Inject to prevent this? I am able to prevent the NPE by changing....

```
private DeviceSessionHandler sessionHandler = new DeviceSessionHandler();
```

But then the application does not behave like the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#section10) says it should under 
 
`Testing the Java WebSocket Home Application` 
`Step 4:` A device is added to the Java WebSocket Home server and it is rendered in both web browsers.

Both Browsers are not updated. Now I don't know if that because of the DI work around, or some other factor. I need help figuring out why the Dependency Injection is not working, and then I can make a determination if that is the cause of differing results.

I can post more code or logcat or whatever you think may be of help.
Thanks!

Comment: Whare are you deploying your example?

Comment: locally using Netbeans/Tomcat, I have not figured out how to host it yet

Comment: The @Inject is just a marker that the member is "injectable".  You need a DI framework to perform the actual injection at runtime.  Are you using a specific DI framework?  If so, which one?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't support CDI natively. The tutorial uses Glassfish, which does.

Comment: @paulk23 I have cdi-api.jar included in my Libaries

Comment: @JBNizet So you said natively, does that mean I can get like a plugin to add the support?

Comment: @chewbapoclypse that doesn't change anything. See https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.3.4.Final/en-US/html_single/#_deploying_to_apache_tomcat, but I'm not sure the websocket thing will be supported. You'd better use a complete Java EE server like Glassfish, Wildfly, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet like dosen't change the fact that it wont work on Tomcat or the part about runtime injection, or both?

Comment: Well I just ran it on GlassFish and it works as intended.

Comment: @paulk23 Can you please expound upon this "You need a DI framework to perform the actual injection at runtime"

Answer (score 1):

Glad you realized that without @Inject, you simply need to new a handler for it, but, that's not good enough, you also need static for it, because you want all of clients sharing the same handler, then any of the client updates the device, all the other clients can see it, I tested it, it worked.

For your second question, besides adding static for that handler, and since you are not using GlassFish, I assume you may need to include the GlassFish "javax.json" lib, or if you are using maven to manage the imports, you should add the GlassFish **implementation**, instead of only **declaration**, so you should add:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I found the root cause by debugging the code, hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks James I ended up not using Tomcat and instead using GlassFish and ended up running into a whole new can of worms when I tried to log in to the admin console remotely, and could only push updates through CLI and shell commands,but I will go back over it and check this out

Comment: no problem at all, and please always remember, different containers simply means different implementation of some API, and if you are missing some lib in one container, simple find it somewhere and add it to your classpath. May the force be with you.